# Angular - dynamic component - bind (click) event

Tags: angular

I'm creating a component dynamically and I need to add (click) handler with $event as a parameter at this dynamic component like we do this at HTML template <div (click)="clickHandler($event)">

```
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
const viewContainerRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

viewContainerRef.instance.message = componentData.message;
```

This click should handle EventEmitter($event)

How do I do this?
Thanks for advance!

Comment: What do you mean by _"This click should handle `EventEmitter($event)`"_? Is there an `@Output()` variable in this dynamic component that should also be handled by the same event handler as the `(click)` event's?

Comment: Yes, the component has the needed @Output()  inside

Comment: What do then mean by the _"add (click) handler"_ to the component? Do you wish to capture a mouse click over the entire component?

Comment: Yes. the component is a chat message and need to handle mouse click on it: <div (click)="handler($event)">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are already available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42022229/6513921) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40725708/6513921).

I'd combine them here with an adjustment from the second answer. Instead of the Angular Renderer, I'd use the RxJS `fromEvent` function to get the events. Additionally RxJS `Subject` + `takeUntil` is used to close open subscriptions. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223749/6513921) for more info.

Try the following

```js
import { fromEvent, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  closed$ = new Subject<any>();

  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  container: ViewContainerRef;

  private _counter = 1;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  add(): void {
    // create the component factory
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      DynamicComponent
    );

    // add the component to the view
    const viewContainerRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);

    // pass some data to the component
    viewContainerRef.instance.index = this._counter++;

    // get `@Output` emitter from the component
    viewContainerRef.instance.emitter
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.closed$))
      .subscribe((event: any) => this.clickHandler(event));

    // add `click` event handler to the component
    fromEvent(viewContainerRef.location.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.closed$))
      .subscribe((event: any) => this.clickHandler(event));
  }

  clickHandler(event?: any) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closed$.next(); // <-- close open subscriptions
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-example-zqw3gg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) (extended from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts)).

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed! Thanks Michael. )) You're the man!